Pass the same parent route extra to a subroute
I'm using Flutter and GoRoute to navigate in my app. I'm using routes and subroutes as well as extra to pass elements from one route to another. However, there is something I don't understand. I created a route ChatScreen and a subroute OtherProfilePage. My ChatScreen needs an extra (my user model) but my OtherProfilePage only needs my user uid.
My route tree is built like that:
GoRoute(
                name: ChatScreen.routeName,
                path: ChatScreen.routeName,
                pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                  UserAccount? arguments = state.extra as UserAccount?;
                  return slideTransition(
                    context,
                    state,
                    ChatScreen(userAccount: arguments),
                  );
                },
                routes: [
                  GoRoute(
                    name: OtherProfilePageTestFuture.routeName + "_from_chat",
                    path: OtherProfilePageTestFuture.routeName + "_from_chat",
                    pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                      String accountUid = state.extra as String;
                      return slideTransition(
                        context,
                        state,
                        OtherProfilePageTestFuture(accountUID: accountUid),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),

However, when I go from ChatScreen to my OtherProfilePage with this function:
onPressed: () {
          context.goNamed(
            OtherProfilePageTestFuture.routeName + "_from_chat",
            extra: userAccount!.uid,
          );
        }

I got this error message:
 ======== Exception caught by widgets library ======================================================= 
The following _TypeError was thrown building _CustomNavigator(state: _CustomNavigatorState#68537): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'UserAccount?' in type cast

I don't understand because normally I just would need to get a String and not a UserAccount. I think it is linked to my parent route extra but I don't have any explanation...

Check my answer

You got this error because you passing wrong value.
pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                /// Here you want state.extra must be null or UserAccount
                UserAccount? arguments = state.extra as UserAccount?;
                return slideTransition(
                  context,
                  state,
                  ChatScreen(userAccount: arguments),
                );
              }, 



onPressed: () {
          context.goNamed(
            OtherProfilePageTestFuture.routeName + "_from_chat",
            /// But here you sended uid which might be a string.
            /// replace this line with extra: userAccount
            extra: userAccount!.uid,
          );
        }


But when I want to go to OtherProfilePageTestFuture, I would like to pass only my String that's why I passed the ID

Then check data type (state.extract is String) before use it . Then take any action.
